# How to delete a row with pgAdmin III?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

For something so obviously obvious I just can't do it at all.

How can I just delete one row without doing the command manually.

[image]

Comment: Can you not use `DELETE FROM public.cargo WHERE <column>='<value>';`? You'd need to be specific with the WHERE clause obviously to delete only the one record.

Comment: I don't see the point in using a tool like pgadmin unless I can do GUI things like `right-click > delete` or `del` on my keyboard... Otherwise I will just continue using terminal :)

Comment: The power of the gui would be if I could select multiple options with a checkbox

Comment: Also, according to [pgAdmin III 1.22.2 documentation » Using pgAdmin III »](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin3/1.22/editgrid.html) it is stated "***To delete a row, press the Delete toolbar button***" so try highlighting the specific row and then doing that.

Comment: Indeed, I saw this also and it did not work for me, sadly.

Comment: This answer helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/46148375/73323

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot, you're looking at the result of a custom query, and pgAdmin doesn't know that this query corresponds to one table exactly, and that the rows could be edited.

The functionality to edit a table in-place is accessible by navigating to the table in the left pane and launching the "View data" command through the contextual menu or toolbar.

See https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin3/1.22/editgrid.html

Also there are a few caveats:

> Important: In order to edit the data, each row in the table must be
>   uniquely identifiable. This can be done using the OID, or a primary
>   key. If none of them exist, the table is read only. Note that views
>   can’t be edited and are read only by design; updatable views (using
>   rules) are not supported at this time